# text input validation for numeric check

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I am seeing a strange issue in flex. I need to reset all text input fields to 0 once the 
user submits the values to be calculated. In the method

```
     private function calculate():void {
       resetToZero();
       var num:Number = parseFloat(s21.text);    
      }  


     private function resetToZero():void {
      //multiple if statements.... existing here..    
     if(s2l.text.length ==0);
 {  
    Alert.show("length is:" + s2l.text.length);
    s2l.text="0";
 }
}
```

When I am running the program I am getting the alert - length is 1. How is that it when length is 1 it is entering the if statement?. The behavior is really confusing and need some light on this. Is there any other way to achieve the above functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of IF statement, which is terminated

```
if(s2l.text.length ==0);
```

Remove **;** from end as

```
if(s2l.text.length==0)
```

Hopes that helps